# How to associate two joining models in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

Lets assume we have 2 AR models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :proposals
  has_many :concerns
end

class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :proposals
  has_many :concerns
end
```

Proposal and Concern are both joining models between User and Job:

```
class Proposal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :job
end

class Concern < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :job
end
```

What I am trying to solve is how to associate proposals and concerns through both user and job. I.e. I want use eager loading etc:

```
proposals.preload(:concerns).map do |proposal|
  # proposal.concerns are preloaded here 
  # and all concerns have same user and job
end
```

My current solution is just simple `concerns` method which lookup over concerns - it's ineffective because do N + 1 queries.

I want to avoid adding redundant foreign key to one of joining models.

Answer (score 0):

This should avoid N+1 queries

```
Proposal.includes(user: :concerns).where(condition: 123)
```

Comment: No, these concerns would include all user concerns, associated with all jobs.

Comment: then you can try adding a condition on `jobs`

Comment: what exactly do you want